# Copying file from unix to network drive

Tags: linux, unix, shell, solaris

Solaris is the os used. I want to copy files from UNIX Machine to windows network drive. I know smbclient,ftp can be used. But is there any other best option i can use?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this option is *better* or not I can't say, but CygWin comes with an NFS daemon program which operates in a similar manner to `nfsd` on UNIX boxes.

You should be able to run that on the Windows box and mount it from Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the Solaris version you are using. Recent ones (10 and newer) include Nautilus (Gnome file browser) which can mount windows shares. Then you can copy files with drag and drop.